# Change Date Format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have date in format dd/mm/yyyy. I have to change to mm/dd/yyyy in code behind of vb.
Can anybody help to change the format?

Answer (score 3):

Use DateTime.ParseExact to parse the dd/mm/yyyy format, then DateTime.ToString to convert the parsed DateTime into mm/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim inDate as Date = Date.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo())

Dim strOutDate as String = inDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
Console.WriteLine(outDate)
```