# How to change Date format from String in Android

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a `String` variable that contains a date.
I just want to switch the format.

Here's my Code:

```
String date = jobItems.get(position).get(job_deadline);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy",Locale.getDefault());
String newDate = null;
newDate = df.format(Date.parse(date));
```

date has = `2015-08-17`

and I want to change it to = `17.08.2015`

My example doesn't work. Also the method `Date.parse` seems to be deprecated.

How can I change the format on a simple way?

Kind Regards!

EDIT:

Thats not a duplicate of that Thread because I'm not using .NET or VB

Comment: `> 1k` such a questions already available in SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733187/change-date-format)

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426492/change-date-string-format-in-android)

Comment: why you downvote instandly on a newbie? No newbies has a chance to get reputation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to parse the date into a `Date` object with the given format, then you can change the `SimpleDateFormat` and format it back into the desired `String`. Like so:

```
private String reFormatDate(String dateIn) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateIn);
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!